# How to find out the edited column name in cell end edit event of grid angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

In my application, **ngGrid** having nearly 10 number of columns, in that half of them are editable one. Once cell editing is completed, then its calling **ngGridEventEndCellEdit** event. its working fine.

But I want to know name which cell is edited.

Is there possible to get edited cell name in the event **ngGridEventEndCellEdit** ?

Or Is there any other event available for returning row with cell edited column name once editing is completed like **ngGridEventEndCellEdit**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var columnName = data.targetScope.col.field
```

This will return column name for edited cell.

```
    data.targetScope.col
```

This will return all information of edited column